# How to restrict select box option base on check box?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm currently developing registration form which has the option to choose either business or professional role.
I want to restrict the option for professional role to only 'Be delivery' option selectable.
How can I do that ?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cFWY.png) 
Here is my site url If it can help. https://www.behealthy.asia/cp/

Thank You

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="company">
<form action="#" method="post" class="do-registration-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="tg-registeras">
            <span><?php esc_html_e('Register As', 'listingo_core'); ?>:</span>
            <div class="tg-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="register_type" value="business" id="business" name="register[type]" checked>
                <label for="business"><?php esc_html_e('Business', 'listingo_core'); ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="tg-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="register_type" value="professional" id="professional" name="register[type]">
                <label for="professional"><?php esc_html_e('professional', 'listingo_core'); ?></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="tg-select">
            <select name="register[category]" class="sp-category">
                <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Select Category', 'listingo_core'); ?></option>
                <?php listingo_get_categories('', 'sp_categories'); ?>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <?php if( apply_filters('listingo_dev_manage_fields','true','sub_category') === 'true' ){?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="tg-select">
            <select name="register[sub_category][]" data-placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Sub category', 'listingo'); ?>" multiple class="sp-sub-category sp-register-ms">
                <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Select Sub Category', 'listingo_core'); ?></option>
            </select>
        </span>
```

Comment: I have edited right now, thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far to solve your problem via jQuery. Generally speaking you would track clicks on the radio buttons and disable/enable options in the select box according to choice.

Comment: I have found a way to load using array with javascript base on radio buttion but I can't get idea how to load the choice from database and remove some item If click on radio button.